# Is there a way for an iPhone app to open safari up at the existing page (not a new window or new url)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an iPhone app and I need it to open up Safari in the same manner as when you tap on it (just opens the window you were last browsing at). I don't want to open a new window or call a new url.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: did you mean open safari without passing any URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not possible as you have to pass an URL with :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```